# get the number of rows in a column in sql table

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I want to basically do, check if there is one row inside the specific column. If there is one row in the specific column, log it.

right now, I am just performing the sql query, and then logging rows.length, but I cant do that, it just gives all the rows in the table. I need per specific column. how do I do this?

```
 var viewStudents = "select * from login where CHILDNAME = '" + req.query.studentName + "'";
    ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        conn.query(viewStudents, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
              
           
                 console.log(rows.length)

           }
```

Comment: "select count(columnName) from login where CHILDNAME = '" + req.query.studentName + "'";

Comment: `select 1 as dummy from login where ... fetch first 1 row only`